# Во время проверки логина/пароля подходит любой пароль

Tags: javascript

Я начинающий программист на JS и я попытался сделать небольшую проверку по типу "логин-пароль". Все бы ничего, но к логину подходит любой пароль. Вот код, укажите на ошибки, пожалуйста!

```js
let users = [];
const newUser = () => {
  let name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  let balance = document.getElementById("balance").value;
  let pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
  users.push({
    name,
    balance,
    pass
  });
  let htmlCode = "";
  users.forEach(val => {
    htmlCode += `${val.name} = ${val.balance} <br>`;
  })
  const data = document.getElementById("data");
  data.innerHTML = htmlCode;
}
const checkPass = () => {
  let passGuess = document.getElementById("passGuess").value;
  let nameGuess = document.getElementById("nameGuess").value;
  if (nameGuess = name) and(passGuess = pass); {
    let htmlCode = "";
    users.forEach(val => {
      htmlCode += `${val.name} = ${val.balance} <br>`;
    })
    const dataCH = document.getElementById("dataCH");
    dataCH.innerHTML = htmlCode;
  }
}
```

Comment: Вы точно пишите на JS?

Comment: `if(nameGuess = name) and (passGuess = pass);` это неправильная строчка. Во первых в JS нет `and`, а есть `&&`. Во вторых не пишут `;` после закрывающей круглой скобки `if`-a. Знак `;` используется для обозначения конца команды и потому когда вы его ставите после `if`, то последующий блок просто отработает как будто не относится к `if`

Comment: В таких случаях лучше прилагать минимальный запускаемый код в Code Snippet-e, чтобы мы могли протестировать. Иногда ошибка кроется не в опубликованных частях, потому бывают трудности при оказании помощи

Comment: равно должно быть двойное еще в условии ==, вместо =

Comment: Я попробовал все, что было сказано, но теперь результата вообще нету.

Comment: @ГлебКлевер в таком случае опубликуйте минимальный воспроизводимый код, вместе с HTML файлом

Answer (score 1):

```
if(nameGuess = name) and (passGuess = pass); {
```

Замените на

```
if(nameGuess === name && passGuess === pass) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Я сам разобрался с вопросом, т.к. понял проблему - я просто забыл указать значения name и pass внутри константы checkPass(), вот и все.